# Ler de arquivo txt para vetor de char

Tags: c, c++, arquivo

Tenho um arquivo `dados.txt` com CPFs (fictícios) nos seguinte formato:

```
382031758-71
647900189-01
460754503-73
696170135-72
```

E assim por diante, sendo no total 500 cpfs. Estou tentando ler cada um e colocar em `char cpf[12]` (porque cada um tem 12 caracteres contando o `-`), porém ao imprimir são impressos três caracteres estranhos tipo `@ýý`

```
int main(){

//abre o arquivo em modo leitura
FILE *dados = fopen("dados.txt", "r");

char cpf[12]; 

fseek(dados, 0, SEEK_SET); //vai para o inicio do arquivo
//fgets(cpf, 100, dados); //pega 12 caracteres 

for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    cpf[i] = fgetc(dados);
}

printf("%s\n", cpf);

fclose(dados);
}
```

Tentei também com `fscanf(dados, "%s\n", cpf);` mas deu na mesma. Assim, gostaria de entender como ler esses dados dessa forma. Quero armazenar em uma variável porque preciso usar isso para testar uma função hash depois.

Comment: Creio que seja por causa que o seu vetor não esteja considerando o fim da cadeia de caracteres, mude `char cpf[12]` para `char cpf[13]`

Comment: não é isso, mesmo que mude para cpf[100] continua assim

Comment: C ou C++ ? O código que tem é C mas marcou a tag C++ e C++ tem formas bem mais simples de ler informação de arquivos, assim como de armazenar em variaveis.

Comment: tanto faz, pode ser em c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A leitura que está a ser feita não só não aloca espaço para o terminador, como também não o coloca. Por este motivo quando tenta mostrar o valor na consola apanha outros valores que estão na memoria que segue onde o vetor de `char` foi alocado.

Para corrigir basta o seguinte:

```
int main() {
    FILE *dados = fopen("dados.txt", "r");

    char cpf[13]; //13 em vez de 12 para guardar tambem o terminador
    fseek(dados, 0, SEEK_SET);

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        cpf[i] = fgetc(dados);
    }
    cpf[12] = '\0'; //coloca o terminador no fim da string
```

Assim como disse em comentário o C++ fornece-lhe formas mais simples de ler arquivos assim como de armazenar strings, que lhe evita precisamente este tipo de pormenores que são fáceis de passar despercebidos.

Em c++ para ler todos os cpfs pode fazer assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream dados("dados.txt");
    std::string cpf;
    while (std::getline(dados, cpf)){ //ler cada cpf até ao fim
        std::cout << cpf << std::endl; //usar o cpf
    }
}
```

Utilizei o [`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) para operar no arquivo como dados de entrada, e fiz a leitura linha a linha à custa de [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).